# Dialog open event fails to fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The dialog opens with the correct title and text and when the dialog closes the clrflds() function is successfully called. However, when the  dialog opens the dialog_close() function never gets called. I have tried everything I can find on the web to resolve this and I still have the issue.  Thanks in advance for your help with this

```
                            var returned = data;
                            if (returned == 0) {
                                $("#dialog_text").text("Login Failed"); 
                                $("#dialog_login").dialog({autoOpen: false});
                                $("#dialog_login").dialog({
                                                    title: "Login Status",
                                                    open: function(){
                                                        dialog_close()
                                                        },
                                                    close: function(){
                                                        clrflds()
                                                        }
                                                    });                                                                 
                                $("#dialog_login").dialog("open");                  
                                //alert('Failed');;         
                            }
                            else if (returned == 1) {
                                $('#login').load('m_insp_grid.html');
                            }                               
                        }
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            alert(error);
        }
    }); 
} 

function dialog_close(){
    setTimeout(function(){$("#dialog_login").dialog("close");}, 3000);
    }

function clrflds(){
    $("#dept_id").val("");
    $("#username").val("");
    $("#pwd").val("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are in a other context, because of function(){...}.

I guess, if you write a console.log or alert instead of dialog_close(); it's get called right?

Try to write:

```
open: () => {
    dialog_close()
},
```

Or

```
var that = this;
open: function() {
    that.dialog_close()
}
```

Also see here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Actually neither of these worked.  That is the baffling thing about this as the function clrflds() gets called just find when the dialog is closed and the syntax for it is the same as the function dialog_close(), i.e. function () {dialog.close()}